# Fading with transition

Tags: javascript, d3.js, transition, highlight, force-layout

In [this `D3` force layout example](http://jsfiddle.net/47J4w/), fading on hovering is done abruptly:

[image]

How to fade correspondent nodes gradually, with transition? I tried to place calls to transition() in several places, but no luck so far.

Current code most relevant to transition is following:

```
function fade(opacity) {
    return function(d) {
        node.style("stroke-opacity", function(o) {
                thisOpacity = isSameCluster(d, o) ? 1 : opacity;
                this.setAttribute('fill-opacity', thisOpacity);
                return thisOpacity;
            });
    };
};

function isSameCluster(a, b) {
     return a.cluster == b.cluster;
};
```

and

```
var node = svg.selectAll("circle")
    .data(nodes)
   .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .style("fill", function(d, i) {
        return "url(#grad" + i + ")";
    })
    // .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.cluster); })
    .call(force.drag)
    .on("mouseover", fade(.1))
    .on("mouseout", fade(1));

node.transition()
    .duration(750)
    .delay(function(d, i) { return i * 5; })
    .attrTween("r", function(d) {
      var i = d3.interpolate(0, d.radius);
      return function(t) { return d.radius = i(t); };
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're setting two attribute/style values, one of them using a non-D3 method which therefore won't pick up any transitions. There are two ways that you could do this that I can think of off the top of my head. First, use `.each()`:

```
node.each(function(o) {
            thisOpacity = isSameCluster(d, o) ? 1 : opacity;
            d3.select(this).transition().duration(1000)
                .style("stroke-opacity", thisOpacity)
                .style('fill-opacity', thisOpacity);
        });
```

Alternatively, you can set the values separately. The code for this may be more intuitive, but then you have to compute the cluster assignments twice:

```
node.transition().duration(1000)
        .style("fill-opacity", function(o) { return isSameCluster(d, o) ? 1 : opacity; })
        .style("stroke-opacity", function(o) { return isSameCluster(d, o) ? 1 : opacity; });
```

Complete demos [here](http://jsfiddle.net/47J4w/1/) and [here](http://jsfiddle.net/47J4w/2/).